# To replace rows in a column of dataframe only when there is a consecutive occurrence of particular value which is less than or equal to three times

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

I am new to coding. I want a logic that works on csv file. My problem statement is.. I got a df with a column.,
[column look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yfuc.png)

What i expecting to get a column as mentioned below.,
[expected_column output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsW1L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code example changes "b" to "c" when there is consecutive occurrence of "b" characters shorter then 4. Does it solve your question?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['a','b','b','a','b','b','b','b']})
df['expected'] = df['item']

idx = []
for r in df.itertuples():
    if r.item == 'b':
        idx.append(r.Index)
    else:
        if idx and len(idx) <= 3:
            df.loc[idx, 'expected'] = 'c'
            idx = []
df
```

Output:

```
    item    expected
0   a   a
1   b   c
2   b   c
3   a   a
4   b   b
5   b   b
6   b   b
7   b   b
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas. I really appreciate your help. what if i have a column with 1000 rows? then how should i code?

Comment: @PallaviC there is no difference in dataframe size - `itertuples` walks through al rows. You just would have to update the script in case of changed rules - like more characters than "b" affected, various conditions for various characters etc. But if you have 10 or 10k rows doesn't matter. I also admit that there are more pythonic/pandastic ways to solve the task (i.e. with `cumcount()` or `diff()`), but this one is simple and easily updateable (and sufficient for beginners like me and you ;) )